# Method copypicture of object range failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem with excel macro which copies range of cells and store them as a picture on shared drive. Problem started I dont know when but it worked nice and suddenly it wont copy the range.

The whole process is like this. I have application in C#, it opens two Excels and runs three macros. That works fine, but last macro started showing errors.

Code below:

```
Sub red_current_status()
    Dim sSheetName As String
    Dim oRangeToCopy As Range
    Dim oCht As Chart
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

    Worksheets("Charts").Range("A1:E15").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    Set oCht = Charts.Add

    With oCht
        .Paste
        .Export Filename:="X:\path\image.gif", Filtername:="GIF"
    End With
End Sub
```

Which shows error:

> "Method CopyPicture of object Range Failed"

What I tried and googled:

- adding cutcopymode false because of releasing memory
- adding screenupdating true, because last excel is set to false
- adding windows state to maximized

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hm, your code worked for me (saving to a Network drive too).  What kind of data are the cells? (Not sure it would matter, just curious).  What if you change the destination drive to a local one, does that work?

Comment: @BruceWayne cells are the mix of regular cells with numbers and text and one image

Comment: It works for me as well. What happens if you run the "macro" from Excel and not from C#?

Comment: I have seen CopyPicture failed sometime for no known reason. I suggest you trap the error and retry the copy if it happens, maybe it will work on the second time.

Comment: When I open the Excel and Run macro manually It works, but when I call the macro from C# App it shows me that error.

Comment: Then put some `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:E15").CopyPicture 1,2`

Comment: @Vityata that fixed it ! :) thanks a lot, finally I got rid of that error, please give it as official answer so everyone can see it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon wow, good tip :)

Comment: @ŠtevkoMarcin - thanks, answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify the Workbook, it takes the `ActiveWorkbook`. The same goes with the Worksheet - if you do not specify it, it takes the `ActiveSheet`. Thus use the following:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:E15").CopyPicture 1,2
```